# Div is slightly off center

Tags: css, html, center

I tried to center a div horizontal and vertical on the screen, but somehow it is slightly off center. Why is that? I think it is because of the content, but I don't know :D

I used

```
height:90%;
```

and

```
margin-top:5%
```

to center it.

Here's the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7mNue/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/j8tBw/

Cleaned up the markup a bit, and applied `display: flex` in a parent `DIV.container` (see links below, specially), and used `center` flex CSS properties.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.inlineflex {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

You may face problems in IE10 and below, other browsers are good (see caniuse link)

References:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Apply `margin: auto` and set a full size (`width` & `height`) on the `DIV`.

Comment: Nope, still off center

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.popup{
    width:100%; // remove this and add below style
    max-width:100%;
}

.popup img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`box-sizing: border-box` on items that have margin and padding should sort it out